# eventListener always fires on first element

Tags: javascript

- There are 3 `<input type="file">` elements on a page.
- Each element has a "change" event listener.

When I click on the 2nd or 3th element, the label of the first is logged to the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/x01e4kgu/3/

**HTML**

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label for="attachment">Upload 1</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment">
  </div>
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label for="attachment">Upload 2</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment">
  </div>
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label for="attachment">Upload 3</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment">
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```js
const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input--upload input')
    fileInputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            const label = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('label')
            console.log(label)
        })
})
```

Comment: Because they all have the same ids. The for attribute in labels tells that which input they are for. All of the 3 labels are for one input with id attribute `attachment` and the first occurrence of that is triggered. So in order to get what you need, you will have to assign different ids for each input and change the for in the labels accordingly. Its a common thing to NOT use the same id for more than 1 html element

Comment: Multiple elements with same id are considered as error.

Comment: Please clarify what do you want, you don't need to add 3 event listeners, cuz we can add  one single listener to the form elements to leverage the event bubble.

Comment: I test the code without the sass style, and this works perfectly

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Thx! You're right. If you post your message as an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @studio-pj done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because they all have the same ids. The `for` attribute in labels tells that which input they are for. All of the 3 labels are for one input with `id` attribute *attachment* and the first occurrence of that is triggered. So in order to get what you need, you will have to assign different ids for each input and change the for in the labels accordingly. Its a common thing to NOT use the same id for more than 1 html element. So the updated code would be:

```html
    <form action="">
      <div class="input--upload">
        <label for="attachment1">Upload 1</label>
        <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment1">
      </div>
      <div class="input--upload">
        <label for="attachment2">Upload 2</label>
        <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment2">
      </div>
      <div class="input--upload">
        <label for="attachment3">Upload 3</label>
        <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment3">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

this way

1. ID must be UNIQUE  (you don't need any one in your code)
   all your `label` elements use the same `for` attribute pointing on the same `id` which all concern **only the first** element having this `id` (the others are ignored)
2. use `onchange` to use an arrow function,
   it's allow you to bypass `e.target...`
   because it's allows you to stay within the scope of your local variable(s) (actualy only `inEl`)

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label>
      Upload 1
      <input type="file" name="attachment[]" >
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label>
      Upload 2
      <input type="file" name="attachment[]" >
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input--upload">
    <label >
      Upload 3
      <input type="file" name="attachment[]" ">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('div.input--upload input')

fileInputs.forEach( inEl =>
  {
  inEl.onchange = e =>
    {
    let el_Lb = inEl.closest('label')
    console.log( el_Lb.textContent )
    }
  })
```