# i got some problem with .parentElement js

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I'm trying to build an ecommerce website. So I am trying to get my parent element of a button `shop-item-btn`, so that I can then update the content, however I am getting different elements returned each time.

The relevant function is `addToCartClicked()`.
Here's my HTML:

```html
<section class="container content-section">
  <h2 class="section-header">Items</h2>
  <div class="shop-items">
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x20 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X20type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>15$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x10 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X10type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>12$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
              Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x2 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X2type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>8$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>13$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">15x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/15X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>14$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">5x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/5X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>6$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px;"
          class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here is my JavaScript so far:

```
if (document.readyState == "loading") {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
   } else {
     ready();
   }

function ready() {
   var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger");
   //   console.log(removeCartItemButtons);
   for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
       var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
       button.addEventListener("click", removeButtonClicked);
   }

   var quantityInput = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-input-quantity");
   for (var i = 0; i < quantityInput.length; i++) {
      var input = quantityInput[i];
      input.addEventListener("change", quantityChange);
   }
   var lengthInput = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-input-length");
   for (var i = 0; i < lengthInput.length; i++) {
         var input = lengthInput[i];
         input.addEventListener("change", lengthChange);
      }

   var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-btn");
   for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
         var button = addToCartButtons[i];
         button.addEventListener("click", addToCartClicked);
        }
}

function removeButtonClicked(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

function quantityChange(event) {
   var input = event.target;
   if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
   input.value = 1;
   }
}
function lengthChange(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0 || input.value > 600) {
    input.value = 75;
    }
}
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target;
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(shopItem);
}
```

I have looked to see if there is something different in my div elements, but it looks ok to me. Thank you.

Comment: **ID MUST BE UNIQUE** !

Comment: You might want to use `event.currentTarget` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: almost 200 lines of code, I strongly doubt that it meets the minimalist criteria of this site https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Wendelin, ty that solve it

Comment: @MisterJojo, that buttons doing the same thing and act the same so i think its ok

Comment: @MisterJojo i know its very odd to post so many code, it was only because i didnt want to be misunderstood and you are right i could tone it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way
*similar solution to this problem  :* [eventListener always fires on first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931387/eventlistener-always-fires-on-first-element/66931668#66931668)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.shop-item-btn').forEach( shopBtn =>
  {
  shopBtn.onclick = e =>
    {
    let shopItem = shopBtn.closest('div.shop-item')
    console.clear()
    console.log( shopItem.querySelector('span.shop-item-title').textContent )
    }
  })
```

```html
<section class="container content-section">
  <h2 class="section-header">Items</h2>
  <div class="shop-items">
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x20 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X20type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>15$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x10 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X10type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>12$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
              Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x2 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X2type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>8$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">10x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/10X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>13$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;"
            class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">15x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/15X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
            placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>14$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
      <span class="shop-item-title">5x5 type pine wood </span>
      <img class="shop-item-image" src="resources/5X5type.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="shop-item-details">
        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
               placeholder="length in centimeters" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div>
          <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>6$ per meter</span>
        <button role="button" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px;"
          class="btn btn-primary shop-item-btn">
          <span id="AddToCart">
            Add To Cart
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```